# How do I execute the checker framework on just one class?

Tags: gradle, checker-framework

## Background

I am using the checker framework with gradle as so:

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
         id 'org.checkerframework' version '0.6.3'
}

checkerFramework {
    checkers = [
            'org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker',
            'org.checkerframework.checker.tainting.TaintingChecker'
    ]
}
apply plugin: 'org.checkerframework'
```

Right now it is looking at all the classes in my build when I run ./gradlew build.  I do not want the checker framework to look at every class but only a particular .java file.

## Question

How do I limit the checker framework to running a static analysis on one .java file?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to only run `javac` on one class.  Your build system has a way to do this, or you can run `javac` on the command line.

Alternately, use the [`-AonlyDefs`](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#askipdefs) command-line option.  It takes a regex argument and suppresses all warnings except those in classes whose names match the regex, even if the checker is run on more classes.

For example:

`javac -processor ... '-AonlyDefs=^mypackage\.MyClass$'`